# Getting Error In "Method on class [rewards_grails.Customer] was used outside of a Grails application" when attempting to lookup Customer

Tags: java, grails, groovy, web-deployment

I'm attempting to follow along the udemy course "mastering-grails" but I'm running into an issue with looking up a customer.  The course is 4 years old so I'm curious as to whether something is outdated, the code is identical to the instructor's.  I tried looking under the course Q&A.

This is the error:

> Method on class [rewards_grails.Customer] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.

This is the method in the CalculationsService:

```
def processCheckin(lookupInstance) {
    // Lookup customer by phone number
    def customerInstance = Customer.findByPhone(lookupInstance.phone)

    // Set up new customer
    if (customerInstance == null) {
        customerInstance = lookupInstance
        customerInstance.firstName = "Customer"
    }
```

This is the method in the CustomerController:

```
def customerLookup(Customer lookupInstance) {
    // Send to CalculationsService to do the logic and pass back 2 things
    def (customerInstance, welcomeMessage) = calculationsService.processCheckin(lookupInstance)
    render(view: "checkin", model:[customerInstance: customerInstance, welcomeMessage: welcomeMessage])
}
```

The course uses grails 2.3.4 and I'm using grails 2.5.6, I'm not sure if this would make a difference.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.70" // or ":tomcat:8.0.22"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        // asset-pipeline 2.0+ requires Java 7, use version 1.9.x with Java 6
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.5.7"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a version of Hibernate in _BuildConfig.groovy_?

Comment: @mkuligowski it says: runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.10" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"

Comment: Please paste the content of your _BuildConfig.groovy_ file. Is _CalculationsService_ placed in grails-app directory?

Comment: What' s the context you are running? I mean to say: this error is using a browser, a test, ...

Comment: is your `CalculationsService` annotated with `@Transactional` or does it have `static transactional = true`?

Comment: @mkuligowski I added it above

Comment: @JorgeAguileraGonzalez I don't understand, I'm running it in a browser

Comment: @injecteer it's annotated with Transactional

Comment: @NSar I'm asking because it looks like it's calling the controller from outside an application, maybe in a test (?)

Comment: @JorgeAguileraGonzalez Yeah that seemed to be the usual culprit when I was googling solutions.  However, I didn't run it in a test.  The code was similar to the instructor's with the only difference being the versions of the tools since it was recorded a few years ago.

Comment: Perhaps there is not @service tag above the service class.